# pandas.tslib.Timestamp date matching

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to find a way to check if item_date contain today's date. But even I hard code it, print True never happen. Anyone know how to solve this?

```
for item_date in buy_crossing_dates:
    print item_date
    print type(item_date)
    if item_date == '2015-03-25 00:00:00':
        print 'True'
```

result:

```
2015-03-25 00:00:00
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Comment: Can you show us what your data actually looks like, also raw input dat and code to reproduce the problem it's hard to guess here without code to reproduct the problem, also you're comparing a timestamp with a string, why do you expect this to work?

Comment: I am a newbie on python so not sure what I am doing exactly :) Anyway, how could I show raw input data to you?

Comment: Even if the interpreter prints `2015-03-25 00:00:00` when you `print(item_date)`, it doesn't mean that the value of `item_date` is `2015-03-25 00:00:00`. What's printed is only a string representation of your `item_date`. You aren't comparing your data correctly.

Comment: The fact remains edit into your question raw data and code that others can use to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options for checking for today's date in a pandas Series of Timestamps ...

```
import pandas as pd

# option 1 - compare using python datetime.date objects
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2016-12-31'))  # Timestamps
python_dates = pd.Series([x.date() for x in dates])           # datetime.date
today = pd.Timestamp('now').date()                            # datetime.date
print(python_dates[python_dates == today])

# option 2 -  compare pandas.Timestamp objects using Series.dt accessor
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2016-12-31'))  # Timestamps
today = pd.Timestamp('now')                                   # Timestamp
print(dates[(dates.dt.year == today.year) & 
    (dates.dt.month == today.month) &
    (dates.dt.day == today.day)])
```

Note: option one uses a list comprehension to convert a pandas Series of Timestamps to a Series of datetime.date objects (using the pandas.Timestamp.date() method).

Comment: May I know how could I change pd.Timestamp('now') to specific date to test my script? eventually will use now instead, but I need to test the script is working first.

Comment: nevermind, got it:today_date = pandas.Timestamp('2015-03-25')

for item_date in buy_crossing_dates:
    print item_date
    print type(item_date)
    if item_date == today_date:
        print 'True'